# Is `N.0 == N && (int)N.0 == N` true where `N` is an integer literal in the range of int?

Tags: c

Is `N.0 == N && (int)N.0 == N` true where `N` is an integer literal in the range of `int`?

Is it true in general or can it be false?

Comment: In general it might be false; there's no requirement that `N.0` be exactly representable in `double`.  If `int` and `double` are both 64-bit on some platform, it seems likely there will be `int` values that are not exactly representable.

Comment: It can be false. Consider `double N.0 = 1.5; int N = 1;`.

Comment: @HongOoi I think you misread the question

Comment: Surely not when `N` is any old integer literal (since the literal may well exceed the maximal representable value of `int`)...

Comment: [Counter example](https://ideone.com/3F2H8T)

Comment: @MattMcNabb OP probably means the case where N.0 has an integral value, true.

Comment: @HongOoi he means for example `3.0 ==3 && (int)3.0 == 3`  . There is no `.5`

Comment: @MattMcNabb but that's not stated in the question.

Comment: In other words, it's not even true that `N == (int) N` when `N` is "an integer literal"...

Comment: @HongOoi I think it is, where he writes `N` it is a placeholder for an integer literal. The syntax `N.0` is illegal

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ah true, I was in R mode where `.` is allowed in object names.

Comment: Trivial example: `0123.0 != 0123`  is false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we rewrite `N.0` as `(double) N`, we get the following:

```
(double) N == N && (int) (double) N == N
```

Then, we can make the implicit conversions into explicit casts:

```
(double) N == (double) N && (int) (double) N == N
```

Obviously, `(double) N == (double) N` is always true.  So it is the second equality that may fail.

Suppose that `int` is 64 bits and `double` is an IEEE double.  Then there are `int` not representable as `double` (such as 2<sup>53</sup>+1), making the proposition false.  Systems with 64-bit `int` are rare, but they exist.  Here, let `^` denote exponentiation.

```
(int) (double) (2^53 + 1) == 2^53 + 1
(int) (2^53) == 2^53 + 1
2^53 == 2^53 + 1
false
```

If `int` is known to be 32-bit and `double` is an IEEE double, then the proposition is always true, because all `int` are exactly representable as `double` in these systems.

### Extended precision

As chux points out, the compiler is free to use something bigger than `double` for `N.0`.  If this type is capable of representing all `int`, then the proposition will be true.  Imagine that the type is called `long double`:

```
(long double) N == (long double) N && (int) (long double) N == N
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implicit conversion
```

Note that the implicit conversion must now be a conversion to `long double`, because those are the rules for `==`.  The result is that the left hand equality is still always true, and the right hand equality is still false for `N` that cannot be represented using the floating-point type.

### Summary

The proposition is:

- *True* if all `int` are representable as `double`.
- Otherwise, *true* if extended precision is used for constants, and all `int` are representable using that type.
- Otherwise, *false*.

Comment: What if `int` is 32-bit but `double` is some random floating point type?

Comment: @xiver77: It sounds like you want to know what the requirements are for the `double` type in C.  For that, I recommend that you just go read the C standard.

Comment: As one likely will not just compare two constants, but one value (very likely the floating point value) will be the result of arithmetic operations, the value will likely have a fractional part, failing the compare. This is one reason why one has to be careful with exact compares for floating point values. Most times a ranged compare is the better choice.

Comment: The existence of `int` which are not exactly representable doesn't automatically make the proposition false. `N.0 == N` will convert `N` to `double` which might give the same value as `N.0` (I think this is implementation-defined)

Comment: @Olaf: I think there are some misconceptions in your comment: floating point operations are typically exact, with rounding, and therefore you can safely use floating point operations without ever producing fractional parts (assuming that is your goal).  The circumstances under which an exact comparison will succeed or fail are generally predictable.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: It is the second conversion which will fail, which has `int` on both sides, so there are no additional conversions.  The first `==` will always succeed, because both sides will always be `double`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp `N.0` is still converted to `int`, that's a conversion. You'd have to show that there was some value such that `N.0` doesn't give a double that falls between `N` and `N+1` (intuitively it seems likely there are many such values)

Comment: Rounding is normally not applies during operaration, but after processing is done to preserve the precision. However, you are right, if OP just has a value rounded to an integer value (not integer variable) in mind. Given the question, that is acceptable (my comment was more of a note, sorry for not tagging explicitly).

Comment: @MattMcNabb: That's easy: we've assumed that `double` is IEEE double and `int` is 64 bits.  IEEE double cannot represent 2^53+1.  Try running the following in Python: `2.0**53+1 == 2.0**53`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Perhaps s/he meant "no implicit conversions".

Comment: I meant "second comparison", which has an explicit cast to `int`, and is therefore `int == int`, and has no additional conversions beyond the explicit cast.

Comment: Note: As a _line of code_ , `N.0` may have precision beyond `double`. i.e. 64-bit,  such as `18014398509481985.0` (2.0**54+1) as compilers can do FP in wider types.  `printf("%d\n", 18014398509481985.0 == 18014398509481985 && (int)18014398509481985.0 == 18014398509481985);` can result in  1.  OP's code does not force the use of `double` like this answer does.

Comment: So in the _general_ case, this answer is right +1.  Yet `N.0 as (double) N` adds the `(double)` cast which differs from `N.0` as is disallows the compiler from using extended precision and so not quite equivalent code.

Comment: @chux: Sorry, but `N.0` has to have type `double`, it is not allowed to have extended precision.

Comment: You are commenting the _type_ of  `N.0`. I was addressing the precision of that the compiler may use.  Consider `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2` --> "evaluate all operations and constants to the range and precision of the `long double` type." C11dr §5.2.4.2.2 9.  With `(double) N`, the compiler is not allowed that latitude "Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and precision), the values ... and of floating constants are evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be greater than required by the type."  So `(double) N` is more restrictive that `N.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I am 'parsing' your question to mean:

```
Given C99 (or C11)

Are there C integer literal values for N such that:

N.0 == N && (int)N.0 == N 
 ^                ^           'N' with a '.0' making it a double literal
       ^                ^     'N' as a standalone C int literal
              ^               cast the double literal to an int
```

There are cases where this is not true.

1. Any time an integer is wider than the [significand representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) of the float:

   a. Cray implements [64 bit ints and 64 bit floats and doubles](http://docs.cray.com/books/004-2179-001/html-004-2179-001/rvc5mrwh.html#QEARLRWH) Cray also implements either IEEE or a proprietary representation for floats.

   b. Any other system that uses [ILP64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) for their 64 bit model and 64 IEEE for floats since 64 IEEE floats only have 52 bits for the decimal.
2. If you read §6.4.4.1 of the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), there are many literal values of `N` where this example statement is not true:

   a. Where the legal literal for an `int` literal is not supported for a float literal (there are many of these, such as `0x1.0p31` is legal integer literal but `0x1.0p31.0` is not a legal double literal

   b. `0123` is a octal literal but `0123.0` is a base 10 double literal, and are obviously not equal (thanks chug)

   c. Integer liters can be legal and larger than the assigned value. Integer literals can be larger than the assigned value of either int or double

Comment: Minor nit: The int need not be wider than a double.  A 54-bit int (we might have had these by now if the PDP line of computers had continued :^) has values that won't convert to 64-bit IEEE exactly.

Comment: @Mike Housky  Minor minor nit: [IEEE binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) exactly represents integers `-pow(2,53)` to `pow(2,53)`. A 2's complement `int54_t` ("54-bit int") should handle `-pow(2,53)` to `pow(2,53)-1`.  So no problem with `int54_t`.  Perhaps you meant `int55_t`?

Comment: @chux: Oops--miscounted.  Thanks for the correction.  Even int64_t fits the nit though since 64 bits is not wider than 64 bits.